# Configuring ftp endpoints in java - how to set "delay"

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have some problems to migrate xml-based camel routes to java. Running the context and routes (i am using Guice) isn't the problem. But until now i am configuring most of the endpoints via uri parameters (not in java).

To be able to reuse the code easily and let the compiler help me (spelling and type of parameters) i want to configure all stuff via setters. (I don't want to fiddle around with string(constants) and concatenate them to uris)

For some endpoints [the manual](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html) is sufficient. But in case of ftp not all parameters seem to be exposed via "FtpEndpoint". 
For examples "stepwise" could be set via `getConfiguration().setStepwise(stepwise);`. So some parameters are set via the endpoint and some via FtpConfiguration.

But in this special case i don't find a method to set "delay". so how to set this?

Is there a general/ unified approach to configure endpoints in java or is this different in each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `delay` is from the `FileConsumer` component and is set via URI parameters with `consumer.delay` (all `FTPConsumer` properties must be prefixed with `consumer.`).

These properties can not be set in `FtpEndpoint` or `FtpConfiguration` but via `getConsumerProperties()`:

```
endpoint.getConsumerProperties().put("delay", "500");
```

Comment: Thanks, that means there is no setter for delay property at all? The big advantage by using setters is the compile time check of property name and type of value.